# Javascript function inside HTML document, where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML page for a restaurant bill calculator but i'm having issues with the javascript/input/form and have been stuck for a while.  I'm not sure why my function is not working when I submit. If anyone has any ideas where i'm going wrong, I would greatly appreciate any help!

Here is my current code (it has to be in one HTML document):

```
<body>
<h1>Restaurant Bill Calculator</h1>
<br>
<form name="billcalculator" method=post onsubmit="calculateBill()">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="tax">Tax Percent:</label>
        <input type="number" id="taxPercent" min="0" max="100" step=".01">%
        <br>
        <label for="price">Price from the menu:</label>
        <input type="number" id="menuPrice" min="0" max="1000" step=".01">
        <br>
        <label for="tip">Tip Percent:</label>
        <input type="number" id="tipPercent" min="0" max="200" step=".01">%
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="calculateBill()" id="submit" value="Calculate Bill">
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
<p id="display">Please click Calculate Bill after completing form.</p>
<script>
    function calculateBill() {
        var tax = document.getElementById("taxPercent")
        var price = document.getElementById("menuPrice")
        var tip = document.getElementById("tipPercent")
        var taxamount = price * tax;
        var tipamount = price * tip;
        var total = taxamount + tipamount + price;

        if (!tax.checkValidity()) {
            window.alert(tax.validatonMessage);
        }
        if (!price.checkValidity()). {
            window.alert(price.validationMessage);
        }
        if (!tip.checkValidity()) {
            window.alert(tip.validationMessage);
        }
        if (tax.checkValidity() && price.checkValidity() && tip.checkValidity()) {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Price: $" + price.toFixed(2) + "\n" + "Tax: $" + taxamount.toFixed(2) + "\n" + "Tip: $" + tip.toFixed(2) + "\n" + "Total: $" + total.toFixed(2);
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console? What do you expect your function to do?

Comment: `validatonMessage` is not a thing.

Comment: You are multiplying and adding DOMElements.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: Take a few minutes and read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation), which explains how the HTML5 Validity API works.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at all of that.  Thank you guys for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get and parse the values.

```
 var tax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("taxPercent").value);
 var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("menuPrice").value);
 var tip = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tipPercent").value);
```

Comment: `tax`, `price` and `tip` contain `Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no action in your form, and are not posting anywhere, you can just remove the post method from `<form>`.

You should also remove the `onclick` function from your input. There is no reason to have both an `onclick` and `onsubmit` handler pointing to the same function.

Then add this to your `calculateBill` function:

```
function calculateBill(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Finally, you should be getting the values out of the DOM elements like so:

```
var tax = document.getElementById("taxPercent").value;
```

These will be strings, so you will have to [use parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: If OP just uses a regular button and not a submit button, then there is no need for `e.preventDefault()`. Also, your "answer" doesn't come close to fully answering the question. As it stands now, this is just a few tips and should be a comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the question says it's 'not working' and that's very broad. These all things that he can fix to help the function work correctly.

Comment: That's exactly why you shouldn't have answered the question. It's too broad and your answer doesn't cover all the issues. That's why it should be a comment. Not trying to upset you. Trying to teach you how Stack Overflow works. You are going to get down voted regularly with answers like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I was unsure of what exactly post did, and was using it off and on to try and troubleshoot.  I appreciate the advice.

Comment: I included your tips and the submit button is still not updating the .innerHTML that i have specified.

Comment: @ScottAmes there were several different syntax errors in your function that probably prevented it from updating the DOM correctly. Here is a simplified example in JS Fiddle to compare against yours: https://jsfiddle.net/rpxt3rt9/3/